# In R, I webscraped a table. Now when I extract its values they are NAs. Can I convert them to numerics?

Tags: r, web-scraping

In my program, I webscraped a table from Yahoo finance. When I extract the values from the table they are listed as NAs. Is there a way I can turn them into numerics?

```
library(XML)
Symbol = "HD"
TableC <- readHTMLTable(getNodeSet(htmlTreeParse(readLines(paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",Symbol,"/options?p=",Symbol,"&date=",1607644800), warn = FALSE), useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE), "//table")[[1]])
TempVolCPosition <- grep("245.00", TableC[,3])
TempVolCVar <- TableC[TempVolCPosition, 11]
print(TempVolCVar)
```

Comment: When I run this it spits out: "42.68%".  And below: data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert

```
TempVolCVar  <- as.numeric(sub('%', '', TempVolCVar))
#[1] 42.82
```

We can also use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
TempVolCVar <- readr::parse_number(TempVolCVar)
```

Answer (score 2):

Columns 3 to 11 are all originally of type character. Before converting to numeric you have to get rid of the text that doesn't belong. You have plus signs, percent signs and hyphens for blanks. Note that the hyphen and the negative sign are the same so to avoid impacting your negative numbers be sure to use gsub with '^-$' and not "-" or you will lose the negative signs.

```
#replace cells containing only a hyphen with blank
TableC[,3:11] <- apply(TableC[,3:11], MARGIN = 2, function (x) gsub("^-$","", x)) 

#replace percent sign with blank
TableC[,3:11] <- apply(TableC[,3:11], MARGIN = 2, function (x) gsub("%","", x)) 

#replace plus sign for positive values with nothing
TableC[,3:11] <- apply(TableC[,3:11], MARGIN = 2, function (x) gsub("+","", x)) 

#convert to numeric
TableC[,3:11] <- apply(TableC[,3:11], MARGIN = 2, function (x) as.numeric(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the dplyr library you can convert select columns to numeric:

```
TableC <- TableC %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Strike, `Last Price`, Bid, Ask, Change, Volume, `Open Interest`), as.numeric))
```

There will still be a couple of NAs introduced where the original value was a dash.  Andrea's solution is cleaner in that regard.